# jQuery selector for a tr with a specific class in a specific table

Tags: jquery

I have a table, like below, and I want to add an event of the click of any tr with the class = hover.

Before the need to include the hover class, this worked: `$('#delegation tbody tr')`; now, I feel like I've tried placing `.hover` in every imaginable location within that selector, but can't seem to get it.

```
<table id="delegation">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="hover">
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Did you try with `#delegation tbody tr.hover`?

Comment: Apparently not, that worked...  If you could answer question, I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
$('#delegation tbody tr.hover')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$('tr.hover', $('#delegation'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you are looking for:

```
$('#delegation').find('tr.hover').on('click',function(){...});
```